# Perverse <del>/code block nesting preview is misleading

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

I just noticed that including code blocks in `<del></del>` seems to work in the preview but does not in the posted result. For example this:

```
<del>Not code but enclosed in del tags

    this is code, in the same del tag
</del>
```

Is rendered like this:
<del>Not code but enclosed in del tags</del>

```
this is code, in the same del tag
```

While writing this question, the preview looks like this:

[image]

However, as soon as I submit, the final question looks like what you see above, the "code" is rendered as code and the `<del></del>` tags are apparently closed before the code block begins.

A different problem occurs if the code block is enclosed in its own `<del></del>`. This, for example, is rendered one way in the preview:

```
<del>not code</del>
<del>
    code 
</del>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

It looks different once the question has been posted:

<del>not code</del>

<del>code</del>

You can easily check this by hitting the [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/223002/edit) link below this question, you will see how the preview differs from the final output.

Granted, this is not a big deal, I can think of very few if any valid reasons to want to cross out a code block like that. Nevertheless, the fact that the preview differs from the final output makes it a bug and perhaps worth fixing. At the very least worth mentioning.

Comment: Well, Markdown isn’t supposed to render inside HTML…

Comment: @minitech yet it does, and in a non-consistent way. Don't get me wrong this is very definition of a minor, unimportant issue and I quite understand if the devs decide it's not worth the time/effort of fixing it. I just wanted to point it out is all.

Comment: The fact that the preview is inconsistent with the final view is indeed clearly a bug, even if the markup needed to trigger it is pretty perverse.

Comment: I'll have to check, but the issue is *probably* due to limitations in JavaScript regexes that prevent the server-side behaviour from being fully replicated on the client...MarkdownSharp is a little bit better (if that's what you want to call it) about handling raw HTML snippets than PageDown.

Comment: @TimStone I don't know if "better"; but it's a bit different because MarkdownSharp uses the PHP-Markdown version of raw HTML handling, while PageDown uses more or less the Gruber original.

Comment: @balpha Well, in the sense that it's more fault-tolerant for these kinds of situations. The original implementation tends to produce a lot nastier HTML when using raw HTML in a way that's not perfectly aligned with the spec.

Comment: @TimStone Yeah, I'm really looking forward to CommonMark in that regard. Much saner. In particular, much easier to understand. People will very rarely write raw HTML, making it all the more important to make the rules simple enough to remember.

Comment: @balpha Yeah, the worst offender is usually people using the `<pre>` tag in multiple places and then not ending it on a new line, left-aligned, which causes bad things to happen in the preview. I remembered answering a bug report about that but I can't find it now, hrm, maybe someone deleted it again.